# What is the principal value of $\tan^{-1}(\frac{-y}{-x})$?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

According to my book, the principal value of $\tan^{-1}(\frac{-y}{-x})$ is $\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-\pi$. However, isn't $\tan^{-1}(\frac{-y}{-x})=\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ and isn't $\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})<\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-\pi$. So, isn't $\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ the principal value of $\tan^{-1}(\frac{-y}{-x})$?

Comment: This is terrible notation. They should have used the "[atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)" function instead.

Comment: Funny.... I was sure I deleted that comment!  I was dead wrong after all!

Comment: Because I was *WRONG*.  (I didn't delete *your* comment... I don't think I can do that.... but I deleted *my* comment because I was *WRONG*)

Comment: @fleablood could you please clarify your position?

Comment: Why?!  Why should I clarify *ANYTHING*?  I posted a comment.  I was WRONG.  So I deleted the comment.  What more can *POSSIBLY* need to be clarified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between $\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})
$ and

$\tan^{-1}(\frac{-y}{-x})$ is that$$
\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})
$$ is located in the first quadrant while

$$
\tan^{-1}(\frac{-y}{-x})
$$ is located in the third quadrant - in the sense that $(x,y),(-x,-y)$ does. Although they both give similar values when plugged in a calculator, the two differs by their location so you must compensate by $\pi$ accordingly to get the angle required **starting from $0$**

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y>0$ then $$\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}= \tan^{-1}\frac{-y}{-x}= \pi/4$$
But primcipal value of $\arg (x+iy)=\pi/4$ but it is $-3\pi/4$ for $\arg(-x-iy).$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, and your book is rubbish.

1. It simultaneously and **contradictorily** claims:

   - the principal value of $\tan^{-1}\frac yx$ is $\tan^{-1}\frac yx$
   - the principal value of $\tan^{-1}\frac {-y}{-x}$ is $\tan^{-1}\frac    yx-\pi.$
2. Its second and fourth claims similarly contradict each other.
3. In fact, the four claims are collectively a mess: they mix up clockwise and anticlockwise measurements, the concept of principal angle, and are notationally inconsistent.

Comment: I get what they are trying to say, but their way of explaining it is pretty bad. They should've used the [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function as @HansLundmark mentions.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic 1. That’s really not the only problem: they claims r still patently wrong even if u write arctan instead of $tan^{-1}$ and treat this as the principal. 2. There is no single interpretation under which the four claims r consistent.

Answer (score -1):

It is not just algebraic equivalence;  the sign of numerator and denominator decides location of the tip of radius vector.

There are four possibilities to determine quadrant placement:

$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{+}{+},\quad \dfrac{-}{+},\quad \dfrac{-}{-},\quad \dfrac{+}{-};\quad $$

For a point $(x,y)$ in first quadrant, its principal argument angle is in the first quadrant.

For a point $(-x,-y)$ in third quadrant its principal argument angle is in the third quadrant.

Co-terminal angle for any arctan function can be obtained by addition/subtraction of $k \pi$, meaning the point can always be taken to the vertically opposite quadrant.