# Isn't the book wrongly taking $\sin^{-1}$ on both sides here?

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

If $\sin(\pi\cos\theta)=\cos(\pi\sin\theta)$, then show that $\theta=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac{3}{4}$.

**My book's solution:**

$$\sin(\pi\cos\theta)=\cos(\pi\sin\theta)$$

$$\sin(\pi\cos\theta)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\pi\sin\theta)\ [\text{Formula:}\cos\theta=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\theta)]$$

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(\pi\cos\theta))=\sin^{-1}(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\pi\sin\theta))...(i)$$

$$\pi\cos\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\pi\sin\theta...(ii)$$

$$\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sin\theta$$

$$\cos\theta\pm\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos^{2}\theta\pm2\sin\theta\cos\theta+\sin^{2}\theta=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$1\pm\sin2\theta=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\sin2\theta=\pm\frac{3}{4}$$

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin2\theta)=\sin^{-1}(\pm\frac{3}{4})$$

$$2\theta=\pm\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$$

$$\theta=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})\ \text{(showed)}$$

This solution is good and all, but if we input the value of $\theta$ in line (i) we will see something interesting:-

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(\pi\cos\theta))=\sin^{-1}(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\pi\sin\theta))$$

$$[\text{Let's input $\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$}]$$

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(164.058809^{\circ}))=\sin^{-1}(\sin(164.058809^{\circ})$$

$$164.058809^{\circ}=164.058809^{\circ}$$

This is what my book did essentially. However, isn't $164.058809^{\circ}$ outside the restricted range of $\sin^{-1}(x)$: $[\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}]$? So, is the line (ii) in the solution of the book valid?

Comment: +1 to your question, not merely because I agree with you, but because of your work shown.  In fact, my reaction is the same as yours.  The range of the arcsin function is $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2.$  This is clearly inappropriate when identifying all satisfying values of $\theta$ within a modulus of $(2\pi)$.  This is regardless of whether you are considering the range of angles to be $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$, or $-180^{\circ} < \theta \leq 180^\circ$ or $0^\circ \leq \theta < 360^\circ.$  ...see next comment

Comment: It may be that I am overlooking something in the author's analysis that prevents his use of the arcsin function from being relevant.  Even if that is true, I personally regard it as irrelevant.  The student should not have to *reverse-engineer* the analysis to determine that the invalidity of a certain step is *harmless*.

Comment: @user2661923 "*The student should not have to reverse-engineer the analysis to determine that the invalidity of a certain step is harmless.*" *PRECISELY*.

Comment: To see why it's wrong: it would be perfectly valid to replace the $\pm$ with just a $+$. ($\cos(\theta) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$ is a valid identity), and therefore arrive at the conclusion (following the author's reasoning) that $\theta=\frac12\sin^{-1}\frac34$ (without the $\pm$). But this would be an incorrect conclusion, since $\theta=-\frac12\sin^{-1}\frac34$ is also a correct solution. That means that the reasoning is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Even though the spirit of the exercise is really asking you to
   [*solve*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3927547/21813) the given
   equation (in other words, for the final line to be *equivalent* to
   the first line), it technically presents an if-then statement, so
   let's not quibble about the author squaring both sides of the
   equation without justification, thereby potentially creating
   extraneous solutions. Let's also not quibble about them needlessly
   applying $\cos\theta=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\theta\right)$
   instead of simply
   $\cos\theta=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right).$

   However, your book is **blithely discarding solutions** in the the
   fourth and eleventh lines, so those steps are invalid; for example

   - $$\arcsin(\sin(\pi\cos\theta)) \not\equiv \pi\cos\theta$$

     (counterexample: $\frac\pi6)$

   [and](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xjmk3pmeqs)

   - $$\arcsin(\sin2\theta)  \not\equiv 2\theta$$

     (counterexample: $\frac\pi3).$
2. As for your main question: the first three lines of the given solution are equivalent to one another, and $\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\pi\cos\theta\right)\right)$ accepts all real values of $\theta.$

---

This is [the **general solution**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7zbuoyfjoi):
$$\sin(\pi\cos\theta)=\cos(\pi\sin\theta)\\
\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\pi\cos\theta\right)=\cos(\pi\sin\theta)\\
\frac\pi2-\pi\cos\theta=2n\pi\pm\pi\sin\theta\\
\cos\theta\pm\sin\theta=\frac12-2n\\
\sqrt2\cos\left(\theta\mp\frac\pi4\right)=\frac12-2n\\
\cos\left(\theta\mp\frac\pi4\right)=\frac1{2\sqrt2}-\sqrt2n\\
=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\\
\theta\mp\frac\pi4=2k\pi\pm\arccos\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)\\
\theta=\left(8k\pm1\right)\frac\pi4\pm\arccos\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right).$$
N.B. The two $\pm$ signs above are independent and not to be combined; in other words, there are four—not two—independent general solutions. To be clear: \begin{align}\theta=&\left(8k\pm1\right)\frac\pi4+\arccos\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)\\&\text{or}\:\: \left(8k\pm1\right)\frac\pi4-\arccos\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right).\end{align}

Comment: You're right about your last statement, but that's not what my book did. Look at what my book did in (i).

Comment: As an engineer, I approve of "$\pi=\frac{\pi}{6}$" and "$\pi=\frac{\pi}{3}$" (the counterexamples).

Comment: @RyanG I've read your answer and I agree with you. However, as I think more about it, $\cos\theta=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\theta)$ seems wrong completely. $\cos\theta=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$ is only true if $\theta$ is negative. $\cos\theta=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$ discards all the positive values of $\theta$ and gives me negative values that I believe are extraneous. Am I right?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic You're asking why line (i) is true for the particular solution $\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{4}\right).$ And my answer explains why line (i) is (and is expected to be) true for all solutions of the given equation, even solutions that exceed $100000^\circ.$

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic When you say, "Look at what my book did in (i)," I compare line (i) to the line before and see that it is a correct inference. But what they did on the line **after** (i) is completely unjustified, as shown in the middle part of this answer. In other words, we all seem to agree that line (ii) is wrong.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Taking the $\arcsin$ on $\sin Q$ was a valid move since $\arcsin$ is a bijection (one-to-one function), and since $\sin Q$'s codomain $[-1,1]$ falls within $\arcsin$'s domain.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Let $\theta=\pi/3.$ Then $\cos\theta = 1/2$ and $\sin(\pi/2 + \theta) = \sin(5\pi/6) = 1/2,$ so $\cos\theta=\sin(\pi/2 + \theta).$ More generally, the + case works fine for positive angles. And likewise the $-$ case works fine for negative $\theta.$ The complaint I have about the use of $\pm$ in $\cos\theta=\sin(\pi/2 \pm \theta)$ is that it falsely suggests that we can rely on that expression to generate a complete list of possible solutions. And the book's author proceeds to act as if that false suggestion were true.

Comment: @DavidK $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$ for all $\theta;$ so, writing $$\cos\theta=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\theta),$$ while needless, *is* actually equivalent to simply writing either $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$ or $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta).$

Comment: That's right. My main complaint about this step is that I think it suggests that writing $\sin(\pi/2\pm\theta)$ is somehow a more "complete solution" than just writing one of the other expressions. But the problem really is the author's utter disregard for additional solutions in the steps that occur after this one. So perhaps my complaint should have been directed there instead.

Comment: By the way, if $n\neq0$ then $\cos\theta\pm\sin\theta=\frac12-2n$ has no solutions in real numbers, so if this is an exercise in real trigonometry I would drop the terms in $n.$ In any closed interval of width $2\pi$ we would choose to example, for example $[-\pi,\pi]$, that leaves us with the four solutions found in your graph, just two of which are in the book.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning shown in the book is incorrect. Indeed, were it correct, then we could make the following deduction.

$$\sin(\pi\cos\theta)=\cos(\pi\sin\theta)$$

$$\sin(\pi\cos\theta)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\sin\theta)$$
This is exactly the same as your step (i), but with a $+$, rather than a $\pm$. That's perfectly fine, since $\cos\theta=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$ is a correct identity for any $\theta$.

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(\pi\cos\theta))=\sin^{-1}(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\sin\theta))$$

$$\pi\cos\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\sin\theta$$

This is the dodgy step. In your example, it works out for the author, but now the statement is genuinely incorrect.

$$\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}+\sin\theta$$

$$\cos\theta-\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos^{2}\theta-2\sin\theta\cos\theta+\sin^{2}\theta=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$1-\sin2\theta=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\sin2\theta=\frac{3}{4}$$

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin2\theta)=\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$$

(assuming that $\theta$ lies in $[-\pi,\pi]$)

$$2\theta=\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$$

$$\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})\ \Box$$

But this is now incorrect, since $\theta = -\frac12\sin^{-1}\frac34$ is also a solution.

Comment: There are also two other solutions within the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. Even in the book (with the $\pm$ symbol) the dodgy step is incorrect.

Comment: @JohnGowers Sir, why do you assume that $\theta$ lies in $[-\pi,\pi]$?