# In $\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}$, how can $a\sin(\theta)$ be substituted for $x$ when finding the anti-derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, trigonometry

$$\int{\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}}dx\tag{1}$$

When finding the above anti-derivative, $x$ is substituted with $a\sin(\theta)$. However, the range of $x$ is $\mathbb{R}-\{-a,a\}$ while the range of $a\sin(\theta)$ is $[-a,a]$.

[Graph of $\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}[a=0.5]$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eghi5tyftz)

Needless to say,

$$\mathbb{R}-\{-a,a\}\ne[-a,a]$$

So, how can $a\sin\theta$ be substituted for $x$ in $(1)$ when the range of $x$ and $a\sin\theta$ are not the same?

---

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4282068/768162)

Comment: The domain of the integrand is $\mathbb R- \{-a,a\}$. I don't see a problem. The substitution can be made when $x\in(-a,a)$. Otherwise, we can substitute$x=a\csc u$, or $x=a\sec u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$\int{\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}}dx\tag{1}$$
>
> the range of $x$ is $\mathbb{R}-\{-a,a\}$ while the range of
> $a\sin(\theta)$ is $[-a,a]$
>
> how can $a\sin\theta$ be substituted for $x$ in $(1)$ when the range
> of $x$ and $a\sin\theta$ are not the same?

On the integration domain $(-a,a)$ (let's call this interval $A$), the substitution $x=a\sin\theta$ with range $[-a,a]$ (let's call this interval $B$) is valid because $A\subseteq B.$

On the separate integration domains $(-\infty,-a)$ and $(a, \infty)$ (let's call these intervals $C$ and $D,$ respectively), the substitution $x=a\sec\theta$ with range $[-\infty,-a]\cup[a,\infty]$ (let's call this set $E$) is valid because $C\subseteq E$ and $D\subseteq E.$

(Alternatively, use the hyperbolic substitutions $x=-a\cosh\theta$ and $x=a\cosh\theta$ for integration domains $C$ and $D,$ respectively.)

But this integral is easiest found using partial fractions, without any substitution.

Comment: Hmm, I see. However, in the case of $\int{\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}}\mathbb{dx}$, $a\sec\theta$ can be substituted for $x$ without any problem as the range of $a\sec\theta=\mathbb{R}-\{a,-a\}=$ range of $x$: we don't need any other trig functions other than $a\sec\theta$ in this case like we needed in the case of $\int{\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}}\mathbb{dx}$, right?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic 1. As Laxmi suggested, $\csc$ too works, but of course we would rather deal with $\sec$ (& $\tan)$ than $\csc$ (& $\cot).$ In fact, in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351901/21813) answer, I explained why I'd rather deal with a $\cosh$ sub than a $\sec$ sub. 2. A valid substitution is not necessarily a useful substitution. 3. More importantly, an integrand like your suggested one requires _no_ substitution (on the other hand, we might consider a substitution if one of the forms in the aforementioned answer appears in the integrand).

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic I) $a\sec\theta$ does *not* have range $\mathbb{R}-\{a,-a\}$; read my 2nd paragraph carefully.  II) In fact, please just re-read my entire answer slowly; then consider whether paragraph 1 applies equally whether the integrand is $\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}$ or $\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}.$

Answer (score 0):

When $x\in (a, +\infty)$, you can substitute $x = a \cosh \theta$, thus
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d x}{a^2 - x^2} = \int\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{a\sinh \theta d\theta}{1 -\cosh^2 \theta}
= -\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{d\theta}{\sinh\theta}
\end{equation}
You can then use $u = e^\theta$ or $t = \tanh\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Of course, you could decompose directly from the beginning
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a^2-x^2} = \frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{a-x} + \frac{1}{a+x}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Someone downvoted faster than their own shadow! I wonder why. Using a hyperbolic trigonometry substitution is quite standard when normal circular trigonometry does not work.