# How to distinguish between explicit substitution (u-sub) and implicit substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$u=2x+1\tag{1}$$

$$x=a\sec\theta\tag{2}$$

I know that $(1)$ is an explicit substitution (u-sub) and $(2)$ is an implicit substitution. I know this because a person told me this. I couldn't have figured it out on my own.

**Questions:**

1. How do I distinguish between explicit substitution (u-sub) and implicit substitution in the future?
2. Do all implicit substitutions need to be invertible?

---

Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2518470/768162), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4368091/768162)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of integrating $$\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$ making an **explicit substitution** means to make a substitution of the form $$v=g(x)$$ (I'm deliberately avoiding using $u$ to draw attention away from its name), where the new variable $v$ is expressed as a function of the original variable.
On the other hand, an **implicit substitution** is of the form $$x=h(v)\quad\text{or}\quad h_1(x)=h_2(v),$$ where the new variable $v$ is the *argument* of some function in the substitution.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your answer! What about question 2?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Isn't Question 2 addressed in that first link that you supplied under "Related"? Points 2 & 3 there.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Btw, your Question 2 is related to point 4 of your 'Related' link #2.

Comment: Is there a difference between the substitutions $u=2x+1$ and $2x+1=u$, both of these are explicit substitutions, arent they? So, there shouldn't be a difference in writing "Let $u=2x+1$" and "Let $2x+1=u$", should there be?

Comment: No difference at all.