# The correct way of solving for $a$ in $a^2 = b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, absolute-value

Given the equation $$a^2=b^2,$$ solving for $a$ gives
$$\sqrt {a^2} = \sqrt {b^2}\\
|a| = |b|\\
a = \pm |b|.$$ How to validly get rid of the absolute value sign on $b$ to get the correct answer $a = \pm b$?

Dividing $a = \pm |b|$ into cases

- Case one: $a = |b|$

  $b = a$ or $b = -a$

  $b = \pm a$
- Case two: $a = -|b|$

  $b = (-a)$ or $b = -(-a)$

  $b = \pm (-a)$

and making $a$ the subject (correct me if I'm wrong):
$$a = \pm b \quad\text{or}\quad a = -(\pm b).$$
I'm aware that $\pm b \neq - (\pm b),$ so, how does the previous line imply that $a = \pm b$ ?

Comment: $a = \pm |b|$ is the same as $a = \pm b$.

Comment: @RamanujanXV doesn't that only work iff $b \geq 0$?

Comment: No,it is always valid.

Comment: @RamanujanXV but if $b < 0$, then i believe it will be $a = \pm (-b)$ and not $a = \pm b$, right?

Comment: But the two solutions $a = \pm (-b)$ and  $a = \mp (-b)$ are the same.Thus,it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: But consider that $\pm b$ means: "either $+b$ or $-b$" which is the same as "either $-b$ or $+b$"- Thus, $-(\pm b)=\pm (-b)=\pm b$

Comment: $a = ±b$ if and only if $a = b$ or $a = -b$... And $a = ±(-b)$ if and only if $a = -b$ or $a = -(-b)$ if and only if $a = -b$ or $a = b$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so it's mathematically correct to say $\pm b = \pm (-b)$?  I thought that's mathematically wrong since we would then be saying $b = -b$

Comment: @RamanujanXV I'm sorry but I don't really understand when you say that they have the same solution. Also, I thought we were talking about $\pm b$ and $\pm (-b)$ and not $\pm (-b)$ and $\mp (-b)$

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali Ah,yes that was a typo. What I meant to say is that $a=b,-b$ is the solution set and it doesn't matter in which way we represent.

Comment: @RamanujanXV so $\pm b$ and $\pm (-b)$ are the same? does that mean they are equal? I'm sorry, I understand that you said they have the same solution set, but does that mean they're equal?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali Yes they are equal.

Comment: IMO it is correct, because what is $\pm (-b)$ ? It is "either $+(-b)$ or $-(-b)$" that is  "either $-b$ or $+b$" that is again: $\pm b$.

Comment: @RamanujanXV if $\pm b = \pm (-b)$, then wouldn't that mean $b = -b$? which I believe won't be right.

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali Well,$\pm b $ means $b,-b$ and $ \pm (-b)$ means $-b,b$.Thus,there's is no difference..

Comment: @RamanujanXV yeah i believe they mean the same thing. but aren't we saying $b = -b$, $-b = -(-b)$? I'm a bit confused about that

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I thought that the order of $\pm$ or $\mp$ matters? so saying $\pm b = \pm (-b)$ will bring the meaning $b = -b$ or $-b = -(-b)$. That's what I know with my limited knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$a = \pm |b|$$ Dividing $a = \pm |b|$ into cases $a = |b|$ and $a = -|b|$
> $$a = \pm b\quad\text{or}\quad a = -(\pm b).$$ I'm aware that $\pm b \neq - (\pm b),$ so, how does the previous line imply that $a = \pm b$ ?

No, it is in fact true that $\pm b=- (\pm b),$ because $$y=\pm x$$ isn't a genuine equation but [notational shorthand](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4660269/21813) for $$y\in\{x,-x\}.$$

---

Even though my instinct is to continue from your first chunk of working by simply writing \begin{gather}a = &\pm|b|\\=&{\pm}(\pm b)\tag#\\=&{\pm}b,\end{gather} there is a caveat.

The intermediate expression $$\pm (\pm b)$$ is arguably ambiguous as to whether the top and bottom signs are meant to separately/independently correspond, i.e., is the expression meant to be understood as \begin{align}&{\pm}(\pm b)\\=&{+}(+b)\:\:\text{or}\:\:{-}({-}b)\\=&b,\end{align} or whether \begin{align}&{\pm} (\pm b)\\=&{+}(+b)\:\:\text{or}\:\:{+}({-}b)\:\:\text{or}\:\:{-}(+b)\:\:\text{or}\:\:{-}({-}b)\\=&{\pm}b.\end{align}

In $(\#)$ and the final line of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4258869/21813), I mean the second interpretation, however, typically, the expression $$(\pm \,a\mp b)$$ is interpreted the first way, as $$\pm(a-b).$$

Summarising: an expression containing multiple occurrences of $\pm$ and/or $\mp$ may be disambiguated from its context.

---

user1015917's answer is the cleanest, as it sidesteps all occurrences of `±`.

Answer (score 4):

$$a^2=b^2\iff a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)=0.$$

So $$a-b=0\text{ or }a+b=0.$$

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this solution ?

Comment: No, there isn't. Probably someone downvoted because the question is trivial out of spite, not that they should have. Upvoted to counter that. +1 :)

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe someone would have liked it to be a comment instead.

Comment: @RamanujanXV: maybe. Some people tend to think that an answer must be long to be good.

Comment: Is it possible to express what you did but using square root instead of factoring it?