# How is my book finding the magnitude of the resultant differently?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics, angle

**Question:**

Forces of magnitude $Q-R$, $Q$, $Q+R$ act at a point in directions parallel to the sides of an equilateral triangle taken in order. Find the magnitude of their resultant.

**My attempt:**

[image]

Let

$$F_1=Q\cos(120^{\circ})+(Q+R)\cos(120^{\circ})+(Q-R)\cos(0^{\circ})$$

$$...$$

$$F_1=-\frac{3}{2}R$$

Again, let

$$F_2=Q\sin(120^{\circ})+(Q+R)\sin(120^{\circ})+(Q-R)\sin(0^{\circ})$$

$$...$$

$$F_2=\frac{2\sqrt{3}Q+\sqrt{3}R}{2}$$

Now,

$$F=\sqrt{F_1^2+F_2^2}$$

$$...$$

$$F=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{12(Q^2+QR+R^2)}\tag{Ans.}$$

**My book's attempt:**

[image]

Let

$$F_1=Q\cos(180^{\circ}-60^{\circ})+(Q+R)\cos(180^{\circ}+60^{\circ})+(Q-R)\cos(0^{\circ})\tag{#}$$

$$...$$

$$F_1=-\frac{3}{2}R$$

Again, let

$$F_2=Q\sin(180^{\circ}-60^{\circ})+(Q+R)\sin(180^{\circ}+60^{\circ})+(Q-R)\sin(0^{\circ})\tag{*}$$

$$...$$

$$F_2=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}R$$

Now,

$$F=\sqrt{F_1^2+F_2^2}$$

$$...$$

$$F=\sqrt{3}R\tag{Ans.}$$

**My comments:**

My answer is different than that of my book's. Also, my $F_2$ is different than that of my book's $F_2$. Also, how come my book wrote $(Q+R)\cos(180^{\circ}+60^{\circ})$ and $(Q+R)\sin(180^{\circ}+60^{\circ})$ in $(\#)$ and $(*)$ respectively? Isn't it true that the [angle between two vectors can't be greater than $180^{\circ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4390688/768162)?

**Question:**

1. Why did I get a different answer than that of my book's?

Comment: The second term in $F_2$ should be $(Q+R)\sin 240$ for you, not $(Q+R)\sin 120$.

Comment: The angle between two vectors is less than $180^{\circ}$, but in this case, you're not looking at the angle between two vectors - you're calculating the components of a single vector. It's a different procedure, and you can plug in any angle measure you want. In this case, you're starting with the positive $x$-axis as $0^{\circ}$, and the vector with length $Q+R$ is at an angle of $240^{\circ}$ relative to the $x$-axis in the counterclockwise (positive) direction. You could also use $-120^{\circ}$ if you wanted, instead of $240^{\circ}$.

Comment: @AmaanM Understood sir. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.