# $\cos\theta=\sin(\theta\pm\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, physics, angle

*This question came in the Dhaka University admission exam 2019-20*

Q) Two particles are oscillating with simple harmonic motion. If their displacements are described by $x_1=A\sin\omega t$ and $x_2=A\cos\omega t$, what will be the phase difference between them at any instant?

(a) $2\pi$

(b) $\pi$

(c) $\frac{\pi}{2}$

(d) $\frac{\pi}{4}$

**My third-party question bank's attempt:**

$$x_1=A\sin\omega t$$

$$x_2=A\cos\omega t=A\sin(\omega t\pm\frac{\pi}{2})\tag{1}$$

The phase angle of the first particle is $\omega t$ at time $t$; the phase angle of the second particle is $\omega t\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ at time $t$.

$\therefore$ Phase difference, $\Delta \delta=(\omega t \pm \frac{\pi}{2})-\omega t=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. So, the answer is (c).

**My comments:**

$(1)$ seems dubious.

$$A\cos\omega t=A\sin(\omega t\pm\frac{\pi}{2})$$

$(1)$ can be broken down to two separate equations $(a)$ and $(b)$:

$$A\cos\omega t=A\sin(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2})\tag{a}$$

$$A\cos\omega t=A\sin(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})\tag{b}$$

$(a)$ is a correct statement. However, $(b)$ seems to be incorrect:

$$A\sin(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})$$

$$=-A\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \omega t)$$

$$=-A\cos\omega t$$

$$\neq A\cos\omega t$$

So, $(b)$ seems to be an incorrect statement. By extension, (1) also seems to be an incorrect statement.

**My questions:**

1. Isn't the question bank's attempt wrong?
2. What corrections have to be made to make the question bank's attempt completely correct?

Comment: The identity should be $$\cos\theta = \sin\left(\frac\pi2\pm\theta\right)$$

Comment: @Blue Yes! Also, I think that the $\pm$ is [unnecessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4258808/isnt-the-book-wrongly-taking-sin-1-on-both-sides-here#:~:text=Let%27s%20also%20not%20quibble%20about%20them%20needlessly%20applying) here. Just writing $$x_2=A\cos\omega t=A\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\omega t)$$

in $(1)$ would've been sufficient to cover all $\theta$.